# Unable to keep the top level control position fix in winforms - user controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control which has 5 panels.
on form load, 5 user controls gets added to the respective panels and eventually all panels gets added as well to user control.

If I set the user control autoscroll property to true, I do get the vertical scroll bar. Using vertical scroll, if I move down to enter values in last control... 
the control at the top goes off i.e. it moves up and down based on my user control scroll position...

Is there any way I can keep the first 2 user control steady when I move the scroll bar down to the last control?

edit: Providing more information.
I can say that the first user control is like header which has save button in it... and thus I want that portion to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set autoscroll on the outer user control.

Put the fixed user control(s) inside the outer user control (optionally inside panels if you need to). Then put another panel inside the outer user control and set the panel's AutoScroll property to true. Put the remaining user controls (wrapped in panels if necessary) inside the scrollable panel.

(*) Note: unless there is some other reason (that is not apparent in the question) there is no need for the extra panels wrapping the inner user controls.